# for loop is executed twice but data is saved only once php ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, for-loop

```
  <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onload="searchVideo();">

<script>
 var data_length =  2;
 for(var i=0; i<data_length; i++){
console.log(i);
 var pageToken = '';
  var numOfResult = 0;
 var maxResults = 200;
 function searchVideo(){
   var separator = ',';
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&pageToken=' + pageToken + '&playlistId=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-&key=Apikey&callback=?',function(data){

    var l = data.items.length;
    pageToken = data.nextPageToken;
    numOfResult += l;
    var itemUrl = '';
      var videoids = [];
         for(var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
          if( j == 0) {
            separator = ',';
          }
          else {
            separator = ',';
          }

            var videoid = data.items[j].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
            var title = data.items[j].snippet.title;
           $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
               url:    'add.php',
               data: { title: title, videoid: videoid }
                 })
              .done(function(data) {
                });
        }

        if( numOfResult < maxResults) {
          searchVideo();

        }

         });
       }
   }
  </script>
</body>
 </html>
```

add.php

```
<?php
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
include 'config.php';
 $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql,$_POST['title']);
 $videoid = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql,$_POST['videoid']);
 $thumbnail_url = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$videoid.'/hqdefault.jpg';
 $sql = "INSERT INTO ytfb(name,video_name,thumbnail_url)    VALUES('$title','$videoid','$thumbnail_url')";
$create_post_query=mysqli_query($mysql,$sql);
     if(!$create_post_query)
    {
   die("Connection failed".mysqli_error($mysql));
     }?>
```

From the above code data is saved only once. The data is not saved twice but am running the for loop twice to save the data twice. SO can anyone help me how to save the data twice using ajax. Only once data is saved the data is not saved twice as I have given length 2 means 2 for loops it should be saved twice

Comment: your for loop execute one time not execute 2 times. if you want to execute 2 times then `j<=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var paylistIdArray=['PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-','PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-'];
var pageToken ='';
var data_length =  paylistIdArray.length;
var numOfResult = 0;
var maxResults = 200;
var i=0;
var paylistId=paylistIdArray[0];
function searchVideo() {
    var separator = ',';
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&pageToken='+pageToken+'&playlistId='+paylistId+'&key= xxxx',function(data){
        console.log(data)
        var l = data.items.length;
        pageToken = data.nextPageToken;
        numOfResult += l;
        var itemUrl = '';
        var videoids = [];
        for(var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            if( j == 0) {
                separator = ',';
            } else {
                separator = ',';
            }
            var videoid = data.items[j].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
            var title = data.items[j].snippet.title;
           console.log("called");
            $.ajax({
               method: 'POST',
               url:    'add.php',
               data: { title: title, videoid: videoid }
           }).done(function(data) {
           });
        }

        if( numOfResult < maxResults) {
          searchVideo();

        }
        if( numOfResult == maxResults && i<data_length) {
            i++;
            pageToken = ''; 
            numOfResult = 0;
            maxResults = 200;
            paylistId=paylistIdArray[i];
            searchVideo();
        }

    });
}
searchVideo()
</script>
```

Comment: Please make ans as useful

Comment: hey dude can you help me regarding one thing if the playlists have different number of videos that is if first playlist has 100 videos and second playlist has 200 videos then the second playlist is not executed becuase pagetoken becoming undefined

Comment: i will check and let you know. (with in 10 min)

Comment: ok i will accept the answer once i get that one and I will not ask any more questions thanks for yout help

Comment: is possible to share you code (like paylistid,etc) i can't see that scenario

Comment: PL_yIBWagYVjyyqx_qPkbat5zufWZOyZEZ, PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-  consider this 2 playlists

Comment: PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14- => 200  PL_yIBWagYVjyyqx_qPkbat5zufWZOyZEZ => 172 is correct

Comment: exchange the playlists make first playlist as second as second playlist as first then it doesnot work

Comment: try this assign `maxResults = pageInfo.totalResults` inside getJSON

Answer (score 1):

as per my comments your for loop execute one time not execute 2 times. if you want to execute 2 times then `j<=1`

problem in this line. i have fixed issue

```
for(var j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
```

i solved issue on local.. your function searchVideo not execute two times. onload function call only first time. i have upload some code sample. you should fallow this sample

sample code. remove function and write code without function

```
  <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

<script>
 var data_length =  2;
 for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
    alert(i);
console.log(i);
 var pageToken = '';
  var numOfResult = 0;
 var maxResults = 200;


            var videoid = "asdf";
            var title = "erwe";
           $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
               url:    'test4.php',
               data: { title: title, videoid: videoid }
                 })
              .done(function(data) {
                });


       }

  </script>
</body>
 </html>
```

test4.php

```
<?php
echo "string";
?>
```

other way to implement the function

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

<script>
 var data_length =  2;
 for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
    searchVideo();
    alert(i)
console.log(i);
 var pageToken = '';
  var numOfResult = 0;
 var maxResults = 200;
 function searchVideo(){

            var videoid = "asdf";
            var title = "erwe";
           $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
               url:    'test4.php',
               data: { title: title, videoid: videoid }
                 })
              .done(function(data) {
                });
        }

       }

  </script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you cant simply change it one one it is L variable how can you replace it with 1 then I cant get complete data from api

Comment: what is the value of `l`. print `l` and show details

Comment: its 50 50 50 50 if the maximum is 200 you can just run program once to checki it , it will give the length of videos in api(how many videos)

Comment: i solved issue on local.. your function `searchVideo` not execute two times. i have upload some code sample. you should fallow this sample

Comment: I need another for loop also in that please see my code

Answer (score 0):

No we called search video function only once.(on page load)
Remove onload function from body tag
Please try this code

```
<script>

function searchVideo() {
    var separator = ',';
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&pageToken=' + pageToken + '&playlistId=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-&key=Apikey&callback=?',function(data){

        var l = data.items.length;
        pageToken = data.nextPageToken;
        numOfResult += l;
        var itemUrl = '';
        var videoids = [];
        for(var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            if( j == 0) {
                separator = ',';
            } else {
                separator = ',';
            }
            var videoid = data.items[j].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
            var title = data.items[j].snippet.title;
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url:    'add.php',
                data: { title: title, videoid: videoid }
            }).done(function(data) {
            });
        }

        if( numOfResult < maxResults) {
          searchVideo();

        }

    });
}

var data_length =  2;
var pageToken = ''; 
var numOfResult = 0;
var maxResults = 200;
for(var i=0; i<data_length; i++){
    console.log(i);

    searchVideo();
}



  </script>
```

but i don't know the below condition inside searchVideo function

```
if( numOfResult < maxResults) {
          searchVideo();

        }
```

Comment: its saving only once the second condition is to fetch all the 200 videos from api because in one call max we can get only 50 videos so using pagetoken

Comment: @HectorBeck Ya. Just now i read the document. now is it working after changing the first for each

Comment: still its inserting only 200 records into the database not 400 records can you please just check once

Comment: Okay console the data after get the details. i am getting "dailyLimitExceededUnreg" error

Comment: may be api key expired

Comment: try this var pageToken = ''; 
var numOfResult = 0;
var maxResults = 200;
for(var i=0; i<data_length; i++){
    console.log(i);
pageToken = ''; 
numOfResult = 0;
maxResults = 200;
    searchVideo();
}

Comment: try this `var pageToken = ''; 
  var numOfResult = 0; 
  var maxResults = 200; 
  for(var i=0; i<data_length; i++){ 
 console.log(i); 
 pageToken = ''; 
 numOfResult = 0; 
 maxResults = 200; 
 searchVideo(); 
  }`

Comment: its same as previous one only it is storing only 200 records

Comment: just declared parameters inside for loop

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var pageToken ='';
var data_length =  2;
var numOfResult = 0;
var maxResults = 200;
var i=1;
function searchVideo() {
    var separator = ',';
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&pageToken='+pageToken+'&playlistId=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-&key= xxxx',function(data){
        console.log(data)
        var l = data.items.length;
        pageToken = data.nextPageToken;
        numOfResult += l;
        var itemUrl = '';
        var videoids = [];
        for(var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            if( j == 0) {
                separator = ',';
            } else {
                separator = ',';
            }
            var videoid = data.items[j].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
            var title = data.items[j].snippet.title;
           console.log("called");
            $.ajax({
               method: 'POST',
               url:    'add.php',
               data: { title: title, videoid: videoid }
           }).done(function(data) {
           });
        }

        if( numOfResult < maxResults) {
          searchVideo();

        }
        if( numOfResult == maxResults && i<data_length) {
            i++;
          pageToken = ''; 
   numOfResult = 0;
   maxResults = 200;
          searchVideo();

        }

    });
}
searchVideo()
</script>
```

Comment: hey i will have 2 playlists so I have kept for loop you have removed that

Comment: did you mean change the playlistId in getJSON

Comment: I need to select the playlist dynamically first time in loop one playlist second time another playlist from array so i need for loop

Comment: did you mean dynamically change the playlistId in getJSON

Comment: i will have playlists in array i need to run them